# Is there a EC2 terminated and or Running event that I can publish to SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to run an AWS lambda function that is triggered by an SNS topic that publishes when an EC2 instance state is changed to `running` or `terminated`.

All that I can find online is relating to Autoscaling group events. Are there events that can publish to SNS when an instance is terminated or created?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/432540/how-to-catch-event-that-the-ec2-compute-instance-is-about-to-stop-start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Cloudwatch event rule for that particular case.

[image: cloudwatch event rule]